# Упругие столкновения окружностей

Tags: анимация, canvas, javascript, физика, алгоритм

В общем, весь день сегодня мучаюсь, никак не могу разобраться что к чему.

У меня есть canvas, где летают 2 (потом будет больше) окружности. Для каждой окружности вызываю конструктор и один из параметров - скорость движения шарика по холсту. Кружок летит прямолинейно и ударяясь о стену сохраняет скорость (меняется только направление). Шарики летят с разными скоростями и они разных размеров. Скорость я задаю так:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

И вызываю интервал, где каждые 10 миллисекунд шарик смещается на 1 пиксель вправо и на 2 вверх. Если он дошел до границы холста, то просто умножаю на -1 его смещение и он, скажем, уже будет смещаться на -1 пиксель вправо (уже влево).

Если шарики встретились друг с другом, то они должны отскакивать друг от друга. [Вот, что я нашел на википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision). В конце есть небольшой подзаголовок **Two-Dimensional Collision With Two Moving Objects** - это мне и нужно. И так, 2 кружка столкнулись, и что у меня есть:

- координаты центра окружности первого круга
- координаты центра окружности второго круга
- радиусы первого и второго круга
- "скорость изменения движения" кругов. (их смещение, как я показал выше).

Для использовании формулы нужно знать угол θ - в какую сторону летел каждый из кругов. делаю так:

```
Math.atan2(y1, x1);
```

Потом нужно как-то вычислить угол φ. Я еще не додумался как. И главное, что меня пугает, функция (формула) с википедии возвращает какую-то "скорость". То есть именно "какую-то". Как мне потом все это перевести в мои "пиксели"? То есть результатом столкновения шариков должен стать факт изменения этих самых **Х** и **У**, на которые каждый момент времени смещается круг.

Ах, да. В формуле есть "масса" - у меня это радиус круга. Вроде все. Надеюсь хоть на какую-то помощь или подсказку. Замучился уже :) Только учусь.

Comment: уменьшите дискретизацию (уменьшите минимальный шаг до как минимум 1/100 пикселя (в реальном мире что-то типа постоянной Планка), оперируйте не пикселями а векторами скоростей, т.к. у вас есть масса то ещё и импульсами. смиритесь что больше 10 кругов на js без webCL у вас красиво не будет.

Comment: 1 пиксель - это я для простоты. Если оперировать не пикселями, а векторами скоростей, как их потом перевести обратно в пиксели? Ведь смещать фигуру я могу только задавая ее координаты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно определиться с обозначениями. У вас должны быть для каждого объекта:

- `x`,`y` - физические координаты положения объекта. которые в каждый момент времени будут вычисляться как `x+V*cos(theta)` и `y+V*sin(theta)` или как сейчас вы вычисляете `x+vx` и `y+vy` (см. ниже)
- `v` - абсолютное значение скорости, в вашем примере оно равно sqrt(5)
- `theta` (θ) - угол направления вектора скорости
- `px`, `py` - пиксельные координаты, которые вы будете вычислять, например как `Math.ceil(x)` и `Math.ceil(y)` соответственно. или с применением масштабирования `Math.ceil(x*scale)`...
- `vx`, `vy` - проекции скорости `v` на оси `x` и `y` (те самые 1 и 2 из вашего примера). из них можно получить и `v` и `theta` и наоборот.

в формулах (только не из википедии, а по ссылке, откуда формулы скопированы в вики) написаны выражения как получить новые `vx`, `vy` для обоих объектов, для их получения используются `v` и `theta`.

самым сложным будет определить момент столкновения объектов.

1. столкновение почти наверное (с вероятностью 1) будет не совпадать с тиками таймера. координаты положения объектов при столкновении нужно будет считать дополнительно, т.е. столкновение произошло не вот сейчас при посчитанных `x` по формуле `x+vx` а чуть раньше. это нужно для правильного вычисления угла фи.
2. как следствие первого. вы должны не пропустить столкновение. при больших скоростях у вас объекты будут пролетать сквозь друг друга, т.е. надо уметь считать было ли столкновение за прошедшее с предыдущего тика время.
3. для количества объектов больше двух вам надо будет проверять столкновения каждого с каждым на предмет какие из них столкнулись раньше. Иначе один круг может два раза столкнуться с другими за прошедший промежуток времени без изменения траектории (как бы пролетел сквозь один, толкнув его, и пролетел по той же прямой и толкнул второй - артефакт).

как посчитать угол фи, думаю вы сообразите, нарисовав прямоугольный треугольник (гипотенуза - центры окружностей, катеты - проекции гипотенузы на оси x и у).

Учитывая вышесказанное, думаю, нужно вести аналитический расчет состояний системы от столкновения до столкновения, т.е. избавиться от дискретности времени. А по таймеру просто отрисовывать всю систему по состоянию на данный момент времени.