# Физика игры. Соударение шаров

Tags: javascript, canvas, физика

Задача - сделать на canvas шарики, чтобы они бесконечно двигались, бились друг об друга. Я это сделал, но это не вполне реалистично. А именно: шарик может ударить другой вскользь, но отлетит в сторону, как будто ударился о стену, тогда как в реальности он бы так и полетел в том же направлении, незначительно увеличив свою скорость по другой оси. Формула не учитывает этого. Так полагаю нужен угол столкновения, тригонометрия. Вот она:

```
vSrt1x = circle.vector.x;
vSrt2x = nearbyCircle[i].vector.x;
vSrt1y = circle.vector.y;
vSrt2y = nearbyCircle[i].vector.y;

m1 = circle.mass;
m2 = nearbyCircle[i].mass;

vEnd1x = vSrt1x/(m1+m2)*(m1-m2)+vSrt2x/(m1+m2)*(2*m2);
vEnd2x = vSrt1x/(m1+m2)*(2*m1)+vSrt2x/(m1+m2)*(m2-m1);
vEnd1y = vSrt1y/(m1+m2)*(m1-m2)+vSrt2y/(m1+m2)*(2*m2);
vEnd2y = vSrt1y/(m1+m2)*(2*m1)+vSrt2y/(m1+m2)*(m2-m1);
```

Здесь vSrt1x - это скорость начальная первого шара по х, остальные соответственно.

vEnd1x - соответственно конечная скорость после удара, содержит формулу в соответствии с законами сохранения импульса и сохранения энергии.
Но как переделать формулу, чтобы она зависела от угла падения.
Последнее, что я пробовал - это такая формула:

```
circle.vector.y = vEnd1x * cos(2*a), 
circle.vector.x = vEnd1y * -sin(2*a)
```

Где a - угол падения

Под углом падения имеется ввиду... угол соприконовения шаров, что ли.
Как программа его находит:

Вычитаем из координаты первого шара, координату второго шара, все по х - получаем катет. Затем делим это на расстояние между центрами (оно находится по теореме пифагора) и полученное значение обрабатываем арксинусом и умножаем на 180/ПИ (переводим в радианы).

Собственно она не сработала. Шарики замедляются, т.е. теряют свою кинетическую энергию, а этого быть не должно.
Кто знает, подскажите! Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: `cos(2*a)` означает угол по отношению к оси OX. А вы думаете что он отразится относительно тела с которым столкнулся.

Comment: Тю! Там наоборот по х sin, а по y cos сейчас переправлю

Comment: Я бы прирост координат задал бы от начальной точки радиус-вектором. После столкновения двух шаров начальные координаты ставил бы место столкновения, а угол векторов пересчитал бы. Но угол зависит от шара с которым произошло столкновение (от радиус-вектора скорости обеих шаров).

Comment: `как переделать формулу, чтобы она зависела от угла падения` Простите, а что есть *угол падения* при столкновении двух шаров, летящих в произвольных направлениях?

Comment: Здесь подразумевается угол между центрами шаров, относительно оси OY. В смысле программа находит разность по х у центров шаров. Это наш катет, затем делит на минимальное расстроение между центрами - это гипотенуза. И с помощью арксинуса находит угол. Таким образом это угол соприкосновения шаров, на какой угол смещены шары, как то так.

Comment: @Akina, не понял сразу вопрос Ваш. Я попробую на пальцах объяснить... Шарики ведут себя так, как если бы они были квадратами. То есть шарик может коснуться вскользь другого шарика, а отскочит в обратном направлении, как от стены. Как будто его удар был центральным.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Николай, я же правильно понял? Расскажите поподробнее! Я мало что понял, но похоже вы правы, что-то с радиус векторами тут.

Comment: Я вашу задачу понял. Попробуйте это решение https://toster.ru/q/31059. Под рукой готового решения нету. Точно могу сказать что нужно либо dx dy обеих шаров обноввить (как на примере) или через радиус-вектор делать. Но тогда на листике аккурано посчитать углы. Вот ещё нашёл похожее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260639/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: Вот это может лучше даже http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444249/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE?rq=1